# Python WebScraping using Soap + Request

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the information of a link using soap in Python. I'm able to get the whole Array with the information, but I don't know how to manipulate the information the way I want.

For example: I want to show online Name(Nome) and Status.

---

I've tried to get only the div, but it return "none" as a result.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('http://apps.cptm.sp.gov.br:8080/AppMobileService/api/LinhasMetropolitanas').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

Comment: You have to use `source.content` instead of `source`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, you don't need `BeautifulSoup` at all. You can directly get the `source.contents`, decode it and use *[ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)* to get a list.

```
import requests
import ast
source = requests.get('http://apps.cptm.sp.gov.br:8080/AppMobileService/api/LinhasMetropolitanas')
content_list=ast.literal_eval(source.content.decode("utf-8"))
for d in content_list:
    print(d['Nome'],d['Status'])
```

Output:

```
AZUL Operação Normal
VERDE Operação Normal
VERMELHA Operação Normal
AMARELA Operação Normal
LILÁS Operação Normal
RUBI Operação Normal
DIAMANTE Velocidade Reduzida
ESMERALDA Velocidade Reduzida
TURQUESA Operação Normal
CORAL Operação Normal
SAFIRA Velocidade Reduzida
```

`content_list` looks like this

```
[{'Nome': 'AZUL', 'Status': 'Operação Normal', 'Tipo': 'M', 'Descricao': '', 'DataGeracao': '2019-04-13T22:50:44', 'LinhaId': 1}, {'Nome': 'VERDE', 'Status': 'Operação Normal', 'Tipo': 'M', 'Descricao': '', 'DataGeracao': '2019-04-13T22:50:44', 'LinhaId': 2}, {'Nome': 'VERMELHA', 'Status': 'Operação Normal', 'Tipo': 'M', 'Descricao': '', 'DataGeracao': '2019-04-13T22:50:44', 'LinhaId': 3}, {'Nome': 'AMARELA', 'Status': 'Operação Normal', 'Tipo': '4', 'Descricao': '', 'DataGeracao': '2019-04-13T22:50:00', 'LinhaId': 4}, {'Nome': 'LILÁS', 'Status': 'Operação Normal', 'Tipo': 'M', 'Descricao': '', 'DataGeracao': '2019-04-13T22:50:44', 'LinhaId': 5}, {'Nome': 'RUBI', 'Status': 'Operação Normal', 'Tipo': 'C', 'Descricao': '', 'DataGeracao': '2019-04-13T22:50:43', 'LinhaId': 7}, {'Nome': 'DIAMANTE', 'Status': 'Velocidade Reduzida', 'Tipo': 'C', 'Descricao': 'Por motivo de Serviços Programados , os trens da Linha 8 - Diamante estão circulando com intervalos maiores entre as Estações Júlio Prestes e Itapevi .', 'DataGeracao': '2019-04-13T22:50:43', 'LinhaId': 8}, {'Nome': 'ESMERALDA', 'Status': 'Velocidade Reduzida', 'Tipo': 'C', 'Descricao': 'Por motivo de Obras de Modernização , os trens da Linha 9 - Esmeralda estão circulando com intervalos maiores entre as Estações Osasco e Grajaú .', 'DataGeracao': '2019-04-13T22:50:43', 'LinhaId': 9}, {'Nome': 'TURQUESA', 'Status': 'Operação Normal', 'Tipo': 'C', 'Descricao': '', 'DataGeracao': '2019-04-13T22:50:43', 'LinhaId': 10}, {'Nome': 'CORAL', 'Status': 'Operação Normal', 'Tipo': 'C', 'Descricao': '', 'DataGeracao': '2019-04-13T22:50:43', 'LinhaId': 11}, {'Nome': 'SAFIRA', 'Status': 'Velocidade Reduzida', 'Tipo': 'C', 'Descricao': 'Por motivo de Obras de Modernização , os trens da Linha 12 - Safira estão circulando com intervalos maiores entre as Estações Brás e Calmon Viana .', 'DataGeracao': '2019-04-13T22:50:43', 'LinhaId': 12}]
```